# Usage of "More concrete" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I was wondering if I can use "More concrete,..." at the beginning of a sentence in order to specify a general statement.

So for instance:

```
The company does not really perform well.
More concrete, the market share of the company dropped by 30%.
```

Is there another term that I can use instead or is it fine to use it?

Comment: The first sentence would sound more natural (especially with the second) written as "The company *has not performed* well."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it like this:

> The company does not really perform well.
>
> To put it more *concretely*, the market share of the company dropped
>   by 30%.

"Concretely" is an adverb modifying "put." You could omit "To put it" if you wanted.

Comment: "Specifically" is another way to call attention to detail.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst valid, I can't recall having seen "concrete" used in this way.

If the drop in market share is the only thing that makes you say the company doesn't perform well, you could say:

> *Specifically*, the market share of the company dropped by 30%.

If the market share is just one instance of poor performance among many, you could say:

> *For example*, the market share of the company dropped by 30%.

Both offer concrete evidence of your initial statement, but don't use the word itself.